# Memory leak in C++ : vector functions in loops

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

I have a situation where multiple functions are called repeatedly. Here is a bare model of the program, how it is supposed to work. When the number of iterations are large the program eats up all the memory (not significant in this bare minimum model), probably a case of memory leak. Please suggest what is the best way in such situations. I am novice. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/* Functions to be called repeatedly (can be in different .cpp files) */
std::vector<int> Func1(std::vector<int> ttt);
std::vector<int> Func2(std::vector<int> ttx);

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> temp1;
    std::vector<int> temp2;

    for (int jj = 1; jj <= 50; ++jj)
    {
        std::vector<int>vect0;

        vect0.push_back(0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 500; ++i)
        {
            vect0.push_back(rand()%100);
        }

        temp1 = Func1(vect0);

        // some other oprations on temp1
        temp2 = Func2(temp1);

        temp1 = temp2;

        // some other operations of calling similar functions
    }
    return 0;
}
// ---------------------------------------------
// Functions:
//Func1
std::vector<int>Func1(std::vector<int> ttt)
{
    std::vector<int>tt2(ttt.size(), 0);

    for (unsigned int ii = 1; ii < ttt.size(); ++ii)
    {
        tt2[ii] = ttt[ii] - rand() % 100;
    }

    std::vector<int>tt3 = Func2(tt2);

    return tt3;
}

//Func2
std::vector<int>Func2(std::vector<int> ttx)
{
    std::vector<int>txx(ttx.size(), 0);

    for (unsigned int ii = 1; ii < ttx.size(); ++ii)
    {
        txx[ii] = ttx[ii] % ii;
    }

    return txx;
}
```

Comment: What is the largest value that `rand()` produces on your platform?

Comment: IMO you don't have a memory leak but using `rand()` to fill vectors probably you use a lot of memory (and consume all resources)

Comment: Holy unnecessary copies, Batman

Comment: I am sorry to use rand() in the code. Actually the vectors are read from an input file and their lengths can very from 1 to few thousands.

Answer (score 2):

Pass your `std::vector`s to your functions by reference and modify them in-place. This will get rid of all the copying, which seems pointless since you don't seem to use the originals.

On a side note :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= (rand() + 1); ++i)
```

This will generate a random number for each iteration, which is probably not what you want (beside being pointlessly unoptimized, it will thrash your probability distribution). You should generate and store your max index, then use it in the condition :

```
for (int i = 1, max = rand() + 1; i <= max; ++i)
```

**Edit:** About that probability skew (yeah, it's not actually relevant, but it itches me now) :

Let N be RAND_MAX + 1.

The expected value of `max` will be N/2. Pretty straightforward, since it's a uniform distribution.

Now for the case with repeated `rand()`s. Let S(n) be the probability to stop at iteration n (given that we reached it already). The formula in the for condition gives us P(Sn) = n/N.

Let X be the number of the last iteration. Now what is the probability to reach iteration n ? Well, it's the probability to continue n-1 times, and stop 1 time. Since all random generations are considered independent, we take the product of it all.

P(X=n) = Pi[i=0 to n-1](1-P(Sn)) * P(Sn) = Pi[i=0 to n-1](1-i/N) * n/N

Now what is the expected value of this... thing ? Simply the weighted mean of the values by their probability, so let's crack on.

E(X) = Sigma[j=0 to N](j * P(X=j)) = Sigma[j=0 to N](j * Pi[i=0 to j-1](1-i/N) * j/N)

And now I'll stop there because my math days are long gone. But if you have a scientific calculator at hand, you'll have the result and be able to see which direction the distribution skews in. Or that I failed completely.

**Edit 2 :** yeah, a calculator. Or [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%28j+*+j+%2F+500%29+*+%28product+1-k%2F500%2C+k%3D0+to+j%29%29%2C+j%3D0+to+500). This site rocks. Anyway, I tested it with N = 500, and the expected value drops from 250 to around 25. So, yeah.

Comment: @sharth : if up to RAND_MAX element are actually needed, well... So be it. Not like we can infer what this code actually does with identifiers such as `ttt` and `tt2`...

Comment: Although I can see how the probability distribution will be ruined in the OP's code, I can't find the words to explain it. I'd like to be able to. Can you sugggest a phrase or two that expand on this?

Comment: That certainly would be fun to watch. Fortunately, RAND_MAX is often SHORT_MAX if I recall correctly. This is very much unspecified, but yeah. @Lightness : I'm working on an explanation better than "you see, randomizing too much will furgle the bazooger".

Comment: Let me know when you've reticulated those splines :)

Comment: Sorry for the use of rand() in the example. There is no distribution involved. The whole scene is about iteration of the functions. I am unable to figure out does the memory occupied by a function used in the previous iteration is released in the next iteration. To be frank, this is my fifth program in C++. I just started few hours back.

Comment: @AttuD : You didn't use dynamic allocation, so each object will be destroyed and free its resources at the end of its scope (its `{}` block, to keep it simple).

Comment: Thanks.. then I might have some other issues. Sorry that I took some of your time.

Comment: Not at all ! Try by passing your vectors by reference, I'd be surprised if it didn't help a **lot**. (Surprised as in, I'll dump my IT studies and go flip burgers because **they** don't need optimizing) @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I've half-reticulated this one. Do you have some reticulant left ?

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is often `INT_MAX` or 2147483647 on Linux. (It's 32767 for MSVC.) Ouch.